# Hash from two arrays/lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashmap

Using two Arrays of equal length, how can I create a Hash object where the elements from one array (the keys) are linked to the elements of the other (the values).

For example in Java I can use HashMap:

```
String[] keys= {"apple", "banana", "cherry"};
int[] vals= {1, 2, 3};
HashMap<String, Integer> hash= new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i= 0; i < keys.length; i++){
   hash.put(keys[i], vals[i]);
}
```

How could do this Python?

Comment: Simply `dict(zip(keys, vals))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) inside a dictionary comprehension to achieve the same result in python:

```
>>> keys = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
>>> values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> hash = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)}
>>> hash
{'apple': 1, 'banana': 2, 'cherry': 3}
```

Answer (score 7):

For posterity, it seems like this should be added as a formal answer. (Taken from the comments.)

```
dict(zip(keys, vals))
```